# Why doesnt Hadoop work with Windows 7 under cygwin?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install and start hadoop 1.1.2 in cygwin on windows 7. I am getting the following issue when attempting to run a simple job:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar pi 10 100

13/04/26 17:56:10 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/username/PiEstimator_TMP_3_141592654/in/part0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

My configuration is as follows:

mapred-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>localhost:9001</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the logs.  There will be a specific exception detailed there, most likely a file access problem requiring you to chmod 755 -R some directory and its contents.

Comment: Which log? There are so many... namenode, secondarynamenode, taskrunner, jobtracker...

Comment: @Damascusi: Check all the logs. Or a simple way is to start the dfs, then run the start script again - it should show that all of the nodes are running, instead of some node is starting. Check the logs of the nodes that are not up and running properly.

Comment: I executed the start-all.sh script. Is there something different between start-all vs start-dfs?

Comment: in later versions start-all.sh has been deprecated in favor of two others.  Check the doc to see which scripts you should be running.

Answer (score 0):

This error not because you are trying to Hadoop on Windows. It's because there is some problem with your DataNode. Along with the point which Chris Gerken has made, there could be some other reasons as well. I had answered a similar question recently. You should have a look at it. [Upload data to HDFS running in Amazon EC2 from local non-Hadoop Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073831/upload-data-to-hdfs-running-in-amazon-ec2-from-local-non-hadoop-machine/16136367#16136367)